# JavaCV: cvThreshold vs Imgproc.threshold

Tags: opencv, javacv

I am playing with JavaCV lib and I am bit confused here. It seems that there are 2 ways (versions) for working with image:

```
// 2 approaches:  
// LEFT                 RIGTH 

cvThreshold      vs    Imgproc.threshold
IplImage         vs    Mat
cvMatchTemplate  vs    matchTemplate
```

From what I read on some discussions on the right column is more new approach and that should be used, but if I take a look on [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) github there are examples just using IplImage.

**My question is: Should I use right or left column approach?**

(Here the version I use:)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Don't use javacv (left), but use official opencv java wrapper (right)

Comment: java cv works but when the light condition changes the accuracy decreases. Even I tried the algorithms for handling light condition but it doesn't give result as required